# RLock evaluated but not used ! Why such an error?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, mutex

Why getting such an error?
The portion of code which used `lock` is below

```
func variableModify() {
    m.RLock
    x++
    m.RUnlock
    fmt.Println("modi", x)
    w.Done()
}
```

Entire Program (below)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var m = sync.RWMutex{}
var w = sync.WaitGroup{}
var x = 1

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        w.Add(2)
        go variableReadOnly()

        go variableModify()
    }
    w.Wait()
}

func variableReadOnly() {
    fmt.Println("read", x)
    w.Done()
}
func variableModify() {
    m.RLock
    x++
    m.RUnlock
    fmt.Println("modi", x)
    w.Done()
}
```

Compile Error

```
./prog.go:28:3: m.RLock evaluated but not used
./prog.go:30:3: m.RUnlock evaluated but not used
```

[Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/kogbzoWtQHX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `RLock` and `RUnlock` are methods, and you should call them with parentheses. Otherwise you're just evaluating the value of the method without assigning it to anything, hence the warning.

Corrected code:

```
func variableModify() {
    m.RLock()
    x++
    m.RUnlock()
    fmt.Println("modi", x)
    w.Done()
}
```